# Weird error of ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tqdm' when run pip install -e but works when using python setup install

Tags: python, installation, pip, travis-ci, tqdm

when I git clone this [github repo](https://github.com/aristoteleo/dynamo-release), I am able to install it via `python setup.py install`. However, the installation fails if tries to use `pip install -e` . with an error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tqdm'`

I looked up this [issue](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/497) and ensured `tqdm` has been installed in the environment.

I also noticed that `travis` service for this package cannot also pass its build and having the same error regarding `tqdm`: https://travis-ci.com/github/aristoteleo/dynamo-release/jobs/367588183

see [screenshot of the error message][1]

[image: img]

Comment: `Dropbox (Personal)` may not be the best location ever. While the issue can be something totally different, I would really consider trying an install from a tamer location without spaces and parentheses.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply! yeah, I indeed tried to install it from a different location, for example, **/Users/xqiu/Desktop/dynamo-release**. it ends up the same issue. Plus how come the travis-ci server also show the same issue when it tries to build it? This issue shows across multiple environments as we tested with quiet a few different computers.  It looks like some issue with pip though but I don't know enough to figure it out myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue. The culprit is simply because you cannot specify specific version of tqdm in your setup.py file. Meanwhile, the specification of package requirement between the pyproject.toml and the setup.py need to match up.